# $V$-$I$ characteristics and circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

The only solution stuck in my head goes through finding the resistance from the slope of the curves and using it somehow in the solution, however, I can't figure out what voltage do I use for X and Y? (The current will obviously be the same for both.)

How does one approach exercises of this type?

Two resistors, X and Y, have I–V characteristics
given by the graph.

[image]

The resistors X and Y are connected in series to the same cell. Estimate
the total current leaving the cell in this circuit.

P. S. The resistors X and Y connected to a cell of emf 1.5 V

[image]

Comment: What is the voltage of the cell?

Comment: I've included it.

Comment: OK. Now, the current is the same through each resistor since they are in series. So, how can you figure out the current?

Comment: I = ε / (Χ + Υ) → Ι = 1.5V / (X + Y)Ω

Comment: Forget equations - solve it using the graph.

Comment: should the current be such that the voltage adds up to 1.5V or something like that?

Comment: So what current did you get?

Comment: ~ 1.0 - 1.1 A, I guess, right?

Comment: Yeah, I read it as just a little below 1.1 A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the $I\ \text{against}\ V$ curve gives the reciprocal of the so-called 'slope resistance', $\frac{dV}{dI}$. This can be a useful concept, but it's not relevant here.

Here are some hints as to how to proceed...

• What quantity is the same for both resistors?

• A family of straight lines can be imagined to be drawn on the graph grid. Each straight line represents a particular value of this quantity.

• What is the relationship between the voltages across X and Y and the voltage provided by the cell?

• If you knew the cell voltage you'd be able to select which of the lines that you imagined is the right one!

Answer (score 0):

The current is the same thorough both resistors; the total voltage drop across both resistors is 1.5 V (neglecting resistive losses in the battery).  With these constraints, using the graphs, you can calculate the current.  What do you calculate for the current?